# ActiveMQ failover protocol not reconnecting to master after restarting

Tags: activemq-classic

I am using ActiveMQ version 5.4 and I have a  [pure master slave configuration](http://activemq.apache.org/pure-master-slave.html). My slave is configured such that starts its network transports connectors in the event of a failure.  My clients are configured using the failover protocol, just like the docs say:

```
failover://(tcp://masterhost:61616,tcp://slavehost:61616)?randomize=false
```

When my master dies, the clients successfully fail over to the slave perfectly.  The problem is that after I recover (i.e. stop the slave, copy over the data, restart the master, then restart the slave), the clients are still trying to connect to the the slave (which does not have any open network connectors at that point). Thus, the clients never reconnect to the master after restarting it.  Is this how it's supposed to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've seen this as well. If you're using the [PooledConnectionFactory](http://activemq.apache.org/maven/5.4.0/activemq-pool/apidocs/org/apache/activemq/pool/PooledConnectionFactory.html), set an expiry timeout on the pooled connections via [setExpiryTimeout](http://activemq.apache.org/maven/5.4.0/activemq-pool/apidocs/org/apache/activemq/pool/PooledConnectionFactory.html#setExpiryTimeout%28long%29). The API documentation here suggests that this will force reconnection to the master broker:

> allow connections to expire, irrespective of load or idle time. This is useful with failover to force a reconnect from the pool, to reestablish load balancing or use of the master post recovery

Comment: Thanks. I checked my configuration and it doesn't look like I'm using PooledConnectionFactory, although it does bring out a good point: I need to look at the configuration on the client side and see if something like what you mention could be happening.

Comment: @Kyle If you're using Spring JmsTemplate at all, caching connections and sessions is essential, or you're almost certainly creating and closing a connection for each message sent or received. [This article](http://singztechmusings.wordpress.com/2011/04/24/problem-with-creating-jms-messageproducer-using-spring-jmstemplate-how-to-solve) explains the pitfalls. You should either use a PooledConnectionFactory, or wrap your ConnectionFactory in a [CachingConnectionFactory](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/connection/CachingConnectionFactory.html).